# CSS Flexbox for a Navigation bar with a logo?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want my .logo to be in the middle for the small screens, and on the left for all of the other screens. The .logo stays on the left until the screen gets big and then moves a little to the right, but I would like it to stay into the middle until the screen gets to the breakpoint for bigger screens. I don't know a whole lot about flexbox, but I was hoping that y'all would be able to tell me how to do this!

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mad Men Software | Sometimes Crazy is Just What We Need</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">  
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
      </header>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my css:

```
/******************************
Flexbox Layout
*******************************/

.header, .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media all and (min-width: 670px) {
  .header, .nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1030px) {
  .nav {
    flex: none;
  }
}


/******************************
Additional Styling
*******************************/

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background: #5fcf80;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  background: url('/HTML/MadMenTransparent/MadMenOfficialLogo.png') center center no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
    min-height: 70px;
  background-size: contain;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 12px 0 12px 28px;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

.nav li:last-child a {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  padding: 8px 16px 7px;
}

.nav li:last-child a:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  color: #fff;
}

@media all and (min-width: 1030px) {
  .header {
    width: 1030px;
    min-width: 768px;
  }
}

/*************************
Clearfix
*************************/

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please provide only enough code to reproduce the problem you are having. Also, your current code when rendered doesn't show any logo. You can include a demo if you wish (see jsfiddle.net). More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can add a breakpoint at ur css like this:

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 700px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    header {
      position: relative;
    }
    header ul.nav {
      margin-top: 150px;
    }
    .logo { 
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       margin-left: -75px;
    }
}
```